# Woman lost in time: Black and white TV show/movie

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I saw this as a child, I watched this in the 1970s or early 80s. A woman tries to call a friend or family member on the phone, but the person who answers basically says, “Sorry, wrong number.” The woman is perplexed, and goes to a large urban library (New York city?) to try to get more information — maybe looking in a phone book or city directory. She talks to a librarian and realizes it’s not the year she thinks it is — she is trapped in another time and begins to scream.

It’s black and white. I used to think it was the ending of a movie, but in recent years I have wondered if it was an episode of a show like the “Outer Limits” or “Twilight Zone” — and yet my searches of plot summaries have not yielded anything.

I believe it was a movie. We had local tv stations that showed old movies. It took place in the 1950s or 60s. The library had those big card catalogs. The woman was by herself when she ran in there from a city street in an urban area. I think she made the call from a pay phone. She got stuck in another time; she didn’t travel there in a machine. It was similar to The Twilight Zone, where something is out of a character’s control.

Comment: Welcome Lincoln, could you take a read of the [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and then see if you can add any important details (decade written/read, was it cinema or made for TV etc.). Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Comment: Not a good match but an example of a very focused on an actress episode https://youtu.be/QSegeI5Qn6A clip of twilight zone episode mirror image - full episode https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7zinw2 some gasps at 7 at 14 minutes.

Comment: Thank you! Watching right now.

Comment: Unbelievably, I think I found the movie. I vaguely remembered the woman being trapped in the library, and when I added that detail to my search, I found an old TV movie that ironically starred Vera Miles, who also starred in the aforementioned Twilight Zone episode. I watched it on YouTube last night: in terms of plot, it tracks, although visually I remembered it having a different look with higher production values. It also has a weird campy ending in the vein of most 60s-70s TV movies. The movie is "Journey to the Unknown,” and the episode is “Matakitas is Coming.”

Comment: Great! Please post it as a self-answer below! :)

Answer (score 7):

Unbelievably, I think I found the movie. I vaguely remembered the woman being trapped in the library, and when I added that detail to my search, I found an old TV movie that ironically starred Vera Miles, who also starred in the aforementioned Twilight Zone episode. I watched it on YouTube last night: in terms of plot, it tracks, although visually I remembered it having a different look with higher production values. It also has a weird campy ending in the vein of most 60s-70s TV movies. The movie is "Journey to the Unknown,” and the episode is “Matakitas is Coming.”[image]

Comment: What a coincidence that it was the same actress!  I'm very happy for you that you figured it out after all these years.

Comment: As a self-answer, you won't be able to accept immediately (you have to wait 48 hours before you can do it, although trying early will tell you how much time is left), but to accept, you click on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].